# In C: I want to take a mix of characters and convert them to lower case

Tags: c, arrays, lowercase

Why does my code not accept the argv[] string?  What do I need to do to fix it?  I want to be able to type in both lower and upper case letters and end up with only lowercase letters in the array.  Thanks for any help.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>  
#include <ctype.h>

int main(int argc, char argv[])
{

  char word[30]= atoi(argv[1]);  // here is the input
  for (int i = 0; word[i]; i++)
    word[i] = tolower(word[i]);

  printf("Here is the new word: %s\n", word);
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
int main(int argc, char argv[])
```

should be:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
```

Besides, `strtol` is a better option than `atoi` as `strtol` can handle failures better.

Comment: My comment is out of the scope of question, but thought to mention it.
If you try to declare a variable inside a for loop without turning on C99 mode you might get error. If you do get this error, declare "i" outside for loop.

Answer (score 3):

You have several problems with your code:

- As [KingsIndian](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13328049/246263) already mentioned, you are missing a * in front of the argv paramter of the main function. This ['Main Function' wiki page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Main_function#C_and_C.2B.2B) contains some more details on this.
- `atoi` is used to convert a string number to an integer number. This is not what you want I suppose. `argv[x]` is already a string (char *), so you can use it directly.
- If you use it directly, you cannot modify it contents (not allowed, I believe). Therefore you need to make a copy. Use `strlen()` to find out the length of `argv[1]`, `malloc()` to create an buffer and `strcpy()` to copy it:

---

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>  
#include <ctype.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  char *word = malloc(strlen(argv[1]) + 1);
  strcpy(word, argv[1]);
  int i;
  for (i = 0; word[i]; i++)
    word[i] = tolower(word[i]);

  printf("Here is the new word: %s\n", word);
  return 0;
}
```

Additional notes:

- It would be better (more robust) if you check the amount of given command line parameters using `argc`!
- In theory `malloc()` can return 0, indicating that claiming the memory did fail. So you should check for this.
- If you only want to print the lower case world, you do not require to first convert it and then print it. Instead, you could directly print each converted character.